# R language, problems with SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: r, rgdal, adehabitathr

The following two scripts will generate a "SpatialPixelDataFrame" object:

```
# FIRST
library(rgdal)
elev.grid <- readGDAL("whatever.asc")
elev.grid <- as(elev.grid, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")

# SECOND
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)
library(adehabitat)
elev.grid <- raster("whatever.asc")
elev.grid.asc <- asc.from.raster(elev.grid) 
elev.grid.SPDF <- asc2spixdf(elev.grid.asc)
```

HOWEVER, the first one excedes the capability of my computing resources when applying it to big (15000 x 16000) grids, and the second one generates an object which I can't use for some of my further analyses. For example, when I use it for krige purposes

```
x <- krige(V3~var, points, elev.grid)
```

I get the following:

**Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula), as(data, "data.frame"), na.action = na.fail) :   invalid type (closure) for variable 'v**ar'

I will be really thankful if somebody is kind enough to tell me how to fix it, whether providing me a trick to bypass the memory/capability issue in the first case (preferably), or fixing the error generated by the second case.

THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE!!!

perep

Comment: Side note: #1 Giving a minimal reproducible example increases chances of getting answers (although it might be difficult here). #2 You might be more lucky at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ (but should make a reference in case you cross-post).

Comment: Thank you @lukeA. Effectively, that's difficult to post a reproducible examble. I repeated the question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218422/r-language-problems-with-spatialpixelsdataframe